# Populating external foreach loop array with SQL results

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I'm a php newbee and I'm trying to populate 3 diferent arrays with a serie of foreach and SQL results. The code actually works, but I keep printing only the last result. Somehow I'm not incrementing the arrays but just writing it over and over. The question is, how to incremente them? Any help is really appreciate!

```
        $online = array();//armazena online
    $ocupado = array();//armazena ocupado
    $offline = array();//armazena offline

$atendentes = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM atendentes ORDER BY nome")or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($atendentes)) {/// Pegar atendentes
    $atendentedb = array($row["nome"]);
}

foreach ($atendentedb as $atendente) {// LOOP SELECAO DAS ATENDENTES; VERIFICAR CADA UMA

    $names  = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();//pega o nome de quem esta online agora

    foreach ($names as $name){//DA UM LOOP, EM QUEM ESTA ONLINE E MARCA 

    //*****************************'ACENDER' se a atendente esta online
    $att = $name->username;
    $att = strtolower($att);

    if ($atendente == $att){//esta atendente esta online
        $att_online = 'yes';
        }//esta atendente esta online
    if ($atendente != $att){//esta nao atendente esta online
        $att_online = 'no';
        }//esta atendente nao esta online
    //******************************************************************

    }//loop foreach quem esta online

    if ($att_online == 'yes'){//se atendente online
    $status = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$atendente'")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)) {
    $statusdb = $row["status"];
    }
        //**************************** VERIFICA O STATUS
        if ($statusdb == 'disponivel'){
        //*******************************
        $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_online FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$atendente'")or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)) {
        $online[] = $row['hp_online'];
            }
        }// se o status é disponivel

                //*********************************  OCUPADOS           
                if ($statusdb == 'ocupado'){
                $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_busy FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$atendente'")or die(mysql_error());
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)) {
                $ocupado[] = $row['hp_busy'];
                }
                    }// se o status é ocupado
    }//atendente = yes  

    if ($att_online != 'yes'){//se estiver offline
        $descricao = mysql_query("SELECT hp_offline, horario FROM atendentes WHERE nome = '$atendente'")or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($descricao)) {
        $offline[] = $row['hp_offline'];
        $offline[] = $row['horario'];
                }
        }//se att nao é online

}// loop foreach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching in a while loop, use the `[]` syntax to append values to an array.  Otherwise, you are just overwriting the same value on each loop iteration.

```
$atendentedb = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($atendentes)) {/// Pegar atendentes
    $atendentedb[] = array($row["nome"]);
    //--------^^^^
}

// Later
$statusdb = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($status)) {
  $statusdb[] = $row["status"];
  //-------^^
}
```

If I missed others in your code, you should change those as well.